# How to draw SVG polygon on openStreetMap programitically in flutter

Tags: flutter, svg, polygon, openstreetmap

Hello I want to use this api [nominatim.org](https://nominatim.org/release-docs/develop/api/Search/#json-with-svg-polygon) to find svg shape and latLng coordiante of one address.
I called this api in flutter and try to show it by Polygon in my flutter code in open street map
this is my code

```
late PolyEditor polyEditor;

List<Polygon> polygons = [];
var testPolygon = Polygon(
  color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3),
  points: [],
  borderColor: Colors.black,
  isFilled: true,
  borderStrokeWidth: 1.0);

@override
void initState() {
super.initState();

polyEditor = PolyEditor(
  addClosePathMarker: true,
  points: testPolygon.points,
  pointIcon: const Icon(
    Icons.lens,
    size: 15,
    color: Colors.black,
  ),
  intermediateIcon: const Icon(Icons.lens, size: 15, color: Colors.black),
  callbackRefresh: () => {setState(() {})},
);

polygons.add(testPolygon);
}

SearchController searchController = Get.put(SearchController());

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: Stack(
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    children: [
      Center(
        child: FlutterMap(
          options: MapOptions(
            allowPanningOnScrollingParent: false,
            onTap: (_, ll) {
              print(ll);

              polyEditor.add(testPolygon.points, ll);
            },
            plugins: [
              DragMarkerPlugin(),
            ],
            center: LatLng(32.5231, 51.6765),
            zoom: 9.4,
          ),
          layers: [
            TileLayerOptions(
                urlTemplate:
                    'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
                subdomains: ['a', 'b', 'c']),
            PolygonLayerOptions(polygons: polygons),
            DragMarkerPluginOptions(markers: polyEditor.edit()),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

I called this api and tried to show this svg as a polygon

```
"svg": "M 13.397511 -52.517283599999999 L 13.397829400000001 -52.517299800000004 
 13.398131599999999 -52.517315099999998 13.398159400000001 -52.517112099999999 13.3975388 
-52.517080700000001 Z",
```

but I dont know how to convert this svg string of coordinate to Polygon and show it on map when called this api and recieve this svg

I used this plugin

```
import 'package:flutter_map_line_editor/polyeditor.dart';
```

the result should be like this
[see this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqHO8.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're facing several problems:

1. The retrieved svg data from nominatim is **not a polygon but a path**
2. Besides it describes a single point i.e. it **doesn't have any height or width**.
3. Quite likely, the polyeditor expects a proper polygon based on an array of geodata based coordinates.

#### Change nominatim query to get polygon coordinates

You could change the query to something like this:
`https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=London&format=json&polygon_geojson=1`

Most address search queries won't return a polygon unless they are a sight or public building like "London+Downing+street+10".
If you're searching for a **city, county, state, district or sight**, the json response will include polygon coordinates describing the border of the queried region.

`polygon_geojson=1` parameter will return an array polygon coordinates that could be displayed on you map.
Unfortunately, you need to change the order of coordinates to use them in leaflet since geojson will return `[lon, lng]` instead of `[lat, lon]`

#### Js example fetching polygon from nominatim

You might translate this example to work with flutter.

```js
function initMap(lat, lon, zoom, coords = [], bBox = []) {
  var map = L.map("map").setView([lat, lon], zoom);
  L.tileLayer("https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
    maxZoom: 19,
    attribution: "© OpenStreetMap"
  }).addTo(map);
  var marker = L.marker([lat, lon]).addTo(map);

  if (coords.length) {
    /**
     * change coordinate order from [lon, lat] to [lat, lon] 
     * and reduce number of polygon vertices to 64
     */
    let polygonPoints = getGeoJsonPoly(coords, 64);
    var polygon = L.polygon(polygonPoints).addTo(map);
  }

  var southWest = new L.LatLng(bBox[0], bBox[2]),
    northEast = new L.LatLng(bBox[1], bBox[3]),
    bounds = new L.LatLngBounds(southWest, northEast);
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}

let query = "City-of-London";
//query = "London+Downing+street+10";
let url = `https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=${query}&format=json&polygon_geojson=1`;
fetchJson(url);

function fetchJson(url) {
  fetch(url)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then(function(data) {
      let result = data[0];
      let type = result.osm_type;
      if (type != 'relation') {
        result = data[1];
      }
      let [lat, lon] = [result.lat, result.lon];
      let coords = result["geojson"]["coordinates"][0];
      let bBox = result.boundingbox ? result.boundingbox : [];
      initMap(lat, lon, 10, coords, bBox);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.error(error);
    });
}

function getGeoJsonPoly(coords, vertices = 0) {
  let coordsL = coords.length;
  let step = vertices != 0 ? Math.ceil(coordsL / vertices) : 1;
  let polygonPoints = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < coordsL; i += step) {
    let p = coords[i];
    let [lat, lon] = [p[1], p[0]];
    polygonPoints.push([lat, lon]);
  }
  return polygonPoints;
}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 90vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.8.0/leaflet.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.8.0/dist/leaflet.css" />
<h3>Query: London+Downing+street+10</h3>
<div id="map"></div>
```

#### Optional: reducing polygon vertices

For better performance you might need to reduce the (usually huge) number of vertices.

While looping through the geoJson coordinate array you might drop coordinates like so:

```
/**
 * change coordinate order from [lon, lat] to [lat, lon] 
 * and reduce number of polygon vertices to 64
 */
function getGeoJsonPoly(coords, vertices=0, round=0){
    let coordsL = coords.length;
    let step = vertices!=0 ? Math.ceil(coordsL / vertices) : 1;
    let polygonPoints = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < coordsL; i += step) {
        let p = coords[i];
        let [lat, lon] = [p[1], p[0]];
        if(round>0){
            [lat, lon] = [+lat.toFixed(round), +lat.toFixed(round)]
        }
        polygonPoints.push([lat, lon]);
    }
    return polygonPoints;
}
```

Comment: thanks friend I done it and now seems that it loaded points on map,
but when I run this code `testPolygon.points.addAll(pointsList);` for 4k points app crashed or lagged for many time, how can I handle it , now I want to use of `geojson` package what is your idea ?

Comment: now I used this API this is correct [API](https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search/?format=json&limit=1&city=london&polygon_geojson=1) _italic_ **bold** 
but how to add this `"geojson":{
"type": "Polygon",
"coordinates": [...]` to my map as a polygon

Comment: please answer to this new question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72641455/flutter-app-crashed-when-adding-multi-thousands-points-to-polygon)

Comment: @mohammad reza shabani: I see you already solved the issue. Just in case: I've added an example of polygon simplification. Still believe this might be a good idea for better point selection and performance - but it's you app ;)