# flutter app crashed when adding multi thousands points to Polygon

Tags: flutter, dart, polygon, fluttermap

I used [nominatim OpenStreetMap API](https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search/?format=json&limit=1&city=london&polygon_geojson=1) to recieve coordinate of london city and try to draw polygon of london city, but cause the number of points is too alot when I use this code

```
       try {
                          await state.getLocationPolygonByAddress(
                              state.foundedAddress[index].address);
                          var foundedSvg = state.foundedSvg;
                          List<LatLng> list = [];
                          setState(() {
                            testPolygon.points.clear();
                          });

                          for (int i = 0; i < foundedSvg.length; i++) {
                            for (int j = 0; j <
                                foundedSvg[i].geojson.coordinates
                                    .length; j++) {
                              for (int k =0;k<foundedSvg[i].geojson.coordinates[j].length;k++) 
                               {

                                for (int z = 0; z <
                                    foundedSvg[i].geojson.coordinates[j][k]
                                        .length; z++) {

                                 /* if(foundedSvg[i].geojson
                                      .coordinates[j][k].first is double  && 
                                      foundedSvg[i].geojson
                                      .coordinates[j][k].last is double) {*/
                                    list.add(LatLng(foundedSvg[i].geojson
                                        .coordinates[j][k].first,
                                        foundedSvg[i].geojson
                                            .coordinates[j][k].last));
                               /*   }
                                  else{
                                    print(k);
                                  }*/

                                }
                              }
                            }
                          }
                          print(list.length);

                         state.clearfoundedAddress();






                          setState(() {
                           testPolygon.points.addAll(list);

                          });
                          print('polyeditor length: ${polyEditor.points.length}');

                        }catch(e){
                          print('error :'+e.toString());
                        }
```

and when try to add list of points to polygon in this line

```
testPolygon.points.addAll(list);
```

app crashed .
but it work good If the number of points is small.

this is my FlutterMap layer

```
     late PolyEditor polyEditor;

  List<Polygon> polygons = [];
 // LatLngBounds boundingBox = LatLngBounds();
   var testPolygon = Polygon(
  color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3),
  points: [],
  borderColor: Colors.black,
  isFilled: true,

  borderStrokeWidth: 1.0);



 @override
 void initState() {
 super.initState();
 //  processData();
  polyEditor = PolyEditor(
  addClosePathMarker: true,
  points: testPolygon.points,

  pointIcon: const Icon(
    Icons.lens,
    size: 10,
    color: Colors.black,
  ),
  intermediateIcon: const Icon(Icons.lens, size: 10, color: 
  Colors.black),
  callbackRefresh: () => {setState(() {})},
  );

polygons.add(testPolygon);


 }

  SearchController searchController = Get.put(SearchController());
  MapController controller = MapController();



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
  body: Stack(
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    children: [
      Center(
        child: FlutterMap(
          mapController: controller,


          options: MapOptions(
            // bounds: LatLngBounds(),


            allowPanningOnScrollingParent: false,


              onTap: (_, ll) {
              print(ll);

              polyEditor.add(testPolygon.points, ll);

            },
            plugins: [
              DragMarkerPlugin(),
            ],
            center: LatLng(32.5231, 51.6765),
            zoom: 4.0,

          ),
          layers: [
            TileLayerOptions(
                urlTemplate:
                    
                'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
                subdomains: ['a', 'b', 'c']),
            PolygonLayerOptions(polygons: polygons,polygonCulling: 
                    true),
           DragMarkerPluginOptions(markers: polyEditor.edit(),),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

the result should be like this
[result picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWykC.jpg)

I want a result like this [link](https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/51800#map=15/51.5149/-0.0933)

Comment: Can you share the crash log?

Comment: it dont show any log just app freezed And after a very long time, it works with a lag

Comment: First thing I would do, is remove the plugins. Does it display the points as a polygon or polyline without the dragmarker and polyeditor ? It's also not clear where your testPolygon code actually is, or when/where it's called, so it may be worth expanding on that.

Comment: It also looks like a lot of points to edit (and it has to redraw them all, and a dragmarker at every single point I guess), This may be one where you want to look at some line simplification, but it's hard to tell from the code

Comment: I updated my flutter code please see it again.
also I used this plugin **package:flutter_map_line_editor/polyeditor.dart**
cause also I want to user can draw a **polygon** manually

Comment: also we can not make simplification the points, cause there are important for me

Comment: I suspect you simply have too many points. There are 23,000 points, all of which will have a drag marker on it.

Comment: yes thats right

Answer (score 0):

**Yes this problem solved** by deleting `import '  package:flutter_map_line_editor/polyeditor.dart';` and delete this lines

```
  DragMarkerPluginOptions(markers: polyEditor.edit(),),
  polyEditor = PolyEditor(
  addClosePathMarker: true,
  points: testPolygon.points,

  pointIcon: const Icon(
    Icons.lens,
    size: 10,
    color: Colors.black,
  ),
  intermediateIcon: const Icon(Icons.lens, size: 10, color: Colors.black),
  callbackRefresh: () => {setState(() {})},
);`
```

in code
@lan say correct answer